# How to use and merge JS modules into 1 file?

Tags: javascript, module, obfuscation

I would like to create 1 single javascript file out of multiple files and modules to ship as one single js file for a small library that will be used in the browser (and reuse some part on nodejs).

How can I achieve this?

```
(function() {

  // Modules are minified
  var blake = require('blakejs'); // The "entire" module in here ~350 lines...

  // Other files are obfuscated
  // File1.js
  var first = function() {}
  first.prototype.doHash = function() {}

  // File2.js
  var second = function() {}
  second.prototype.doSomethingElse = function() {}

  //OtherFile.js

  //Webworker.js

}).call(this)
```

I'm using Javascript Obfuscator to obfuscate the script, but I'd like to apply other minification/obfuscation settings to modules, as they wouldn't need obfuscation, only minification.

```
gulp.task('minify', function () {
  return gulp
      .src('./src/file1.js')
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(javascriptObfuscator())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
})
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I would recommend using ES6 modules with a bundler like Rollup, but surely also Gulp can concat multiple files.