# How to optimize/arrange scope of a browser library with a lot of functions? (Good practice)

Tags: javascript, optimization, module, scope

I got a JS file with ~ 2000 lines of code (not minified/with comments) and I'm looking to optimize how functions are stored and the scope of them to avoid spamming the global scope. AKA create something nice.

This is my first "module/library".

Let's start with a simple library that will be included in a webpage:

```
(function() {
  console.log('Awesome')
}).call(this)
```

The library can be called inside a webpage, an IFrame or a webworker and have different functions depending on the environment.

Right now my approach is similar to this:

MyModule.js:

```
(function() {
  // Detect if running in a webworker
  function isWebworker() {
    if (window.document === undefined) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // Detect if the script is running inside an IFrame
  function isIFrame () {
      try {
          return window.self !== window.top;
      } catch (e) {
          return true;
      }
  }

  function createModal() {}
  function clickModal() {}
  function calculate() {}
  function createWorker() {}

  if(isWebworker()) {
    var ww = function() {}
    ww.prototype.size = 512;
    ww.prototype.calc = calculate;
  } else if(isIFrame()) {
    // Some functions here will be in window.MyModule, others are private.
  } else {
    // Is main window - probably
    // Some functions here will be in window.MyModule, others are private.
    var drawer = function() {}
    drawer.prototype.drawtime = null;
    drawer.prototype.draw = draw;
    if(window.MyModule) {
      window.MyModule = {};
      window.MyModule.drawer = drawer;
    } else {
      window.MyModule.drawer = drawer;
    }

  }
}).call(this)
```

includeMyModule.js (used only in main window):

```
(function() {
  var ModuleName = 'MyModule';
  if (!window[ModuleName]) {
    window[ModuleName] = {};
  }
  window[ModuleName].ready = window[ModuleName].ready || function(rd) {
    (window[ModuleName]['rand'] = window[ModuleName]['rand'] || []).push(rd);
  };

  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;
  s.src = '/MyModule.min.js';

  var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);
})();
```

I hope I made sense.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*maximize the efficiency of how functions are stored and the scope of them*", can you explain? You can "*avoid spamming the DOM*" (I assume you mean the global scope) by creating only a single global variable for your module (which your code does - `MyModule`). There are however dozens of ways to achieve that, and none is "better" than the other.

Comment: @Bergi yes global scope, sorry. I edited to "optimize how functions are stored" which make more sense. Like is this a good practice or am I doing something terribly wrong here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, but it seems you're doing some terribly weird things. Having your library export different things in different contexts (workers, iframes, normal) for example. Also in the code you posted it is a bit unclear what the actual library functions are and what the wiring parts (where you are creating the module object) are that you're asking about.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm just trying to fit many things in one file :P See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596007/how-to-use-and-merge-js-modules-into-1-file (unanswered)